# Use the given formula to prove the polynomial must have a zero

Tags: complex-analysis

It is a corollary result of Cauchy Integral Formula:

$$f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(a+re^{i\theta})d\theta . \tag{i}$$

Now we wish to use this result to show that for P(z) = Let P(z) = $z^n + ... + c_{1}z + c_0 $ be a polynomial of degree
n, there must be a point such that P(a) = 0.

Now I think to prove the result is not hard. We assume that there is no zero point, $\frac{1}{P(z)} $ analytic. Note for sufficiently large |z|  we can force $|\frac{c_{n-1}}{z} + ...+\frac{c_{0}}{z^n}| $ to be under $\frac{1}{2} $ forcing $\frac{1}{P(z)} $ to be constant, and reaching a contradicton.

But I don't know how (i) can help here. In general, I feel that the use of this corollary is somehow limited.

Comment: I had no idea that, if $P$ is a non-constant polynomial function, then $\frac1P$ would also be a polynomial function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{f(a)} =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{f(a+re^{i\theta} )} d\theta \to0$$
as $r\to\infty$ if $\deg f\geq 2$ and $f$ is a polynomial without zeros. This gives contradiction